# show previous month dates at the starting of current month

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, angular-material-7

I just started with angular material and I came across using date-picker from angular material 7 and I want to know if is there any way to show previous month dates (as greyed out) in current month instead of empty space at the beginning?

Comment: Nope, it's imposible, see that the first row it's used to show the name of the month with, e.g. in october a colspan=5.